# Updating my element id's so they are in chronological order when sorting them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list that can be sorted, new items can also be added to the list. I have a hidden input with each item that has a value number which is the sortorder.

My problem now is that when I have for example 3 items added they are sorted like this:

```
1 Item 1
2 item 2
3 Item 3
```

But if I drag Item 3 to place 1 it looks like this:

```
3 Item 3
1 Item 1
2 Item 2
```

While I need this in order to save them to my ordering table in my database:

```
1 Item 3
2 Item 1
3 Item 2
```

This is what my html looks like without altering the list:

```
<form id="lijstform">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <label class="lijstnaamtitle">Lijst naam</label>
      <label class="displaynonecoid" id="coid"><?PHP echo $getbedrijfinfo['id']; ?></label>
      <input class="form-control name_list catinput lijsttitle" type="text" name="lijsttitle">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="dynamic_field">
    <div class="row sortwrap">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput" />
        <input type="hidden" name="sortorder" value="1">
        <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
        <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
              <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And I am able to sort the items and change the values of the sortorder input with jQuery, which looks like this:

```
const template =
'<div class="row sortwrap">'+
'  <div class="col-md-8">'+
'    <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list catinput" />'+
'    <input type="hidden" name="sortorder" value="1">'+
'    <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>'+
'    <div class="questionlist questionwrap">'+
'      <div class="row">'+
'        <div class="col-md-8">'+
'          <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>'+
'          <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput" />'+
'        </div>'+
'        <div class="col-md-4">'+
'        </div>'+
'      </div>'+
'      </div>'+
'    </div>'+
'    <div class="col-md-4"> '+
'    <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>'+
'  </div> '+
'</div>';
const vraagTemplate =
'<div class="row" id="question">' +
'  <div class="col-md-8">' +
'    <input type="text" name="question[]" class="form-control name_list questioninput" />' +
'  </div>' +
'  <div class="col-md-4">' +
'    <button class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button>' +
'  </div>' +
'</div>';

// Count numbers and change accordingly when field is deleted
function updatePlaceholders() {
  $('#input-field-id').val($('#input-field-id').val() + 'more text');
  // Sortable code
  let df = $('#dynamic_field');
  df.find('input[name^=cat]').each(function(i) {
    // Als id niet bestaat doe het volgende (anders worden alle ids opnieuw geupdate)
    if (!this.placeholder)
      $(this).attr("placeholder", i + 1 + ". Voeg een categorie toe");
  });
  df.find('input[name^=sortorder]').each(function(i) {
    // Als id niet bestaat doe het volgende (anders worden alle ids opnieuw geupdate)
    if (!this.id)
      $(this).val(i + 1);
  });
  df.find('.questionlist').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input[name^=qu]').each(function(i) {
      $(this).attr("placeholder", i + 1 + ". Voeg een vraag toe");
    });
  });
}
// Append question template
$('#dynamic_field').on('click', '.questionbutton', function() {
  let $ql = $(this).closest('.questionlist');
  $ql.append($(vraagTemplate));
  updatePlaceholders();
});

// Delete
$('#dynamic_field').on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  updatePlaceholders();
});
$('#addcategory').on('click', function() {
let t = $(template)
  $('#dynamic_field').append(t);
  updatePlaceholders();
});

$(function() {
  $('#addcategory').trigger('click');
  $('#question').sortable({
    connectWith: '#question'
  });
  $('#dynamic_field').sortable({
    cancel: '.questionwrap, input',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
  });
});
```

This line needs to be changed:

```
df.find('input[name^=sortorder]').each(function(i) {
    // Als id niet bestaat doe het volgende (anders worden alle ids opnieuw geupdate)
    if (!this.id)
      $(this).val(i + 1);
  });
```

I've tried removing the if statement but it does not work.

Comment: You should ideally leave the IDs as they are, unless they actually relate to something in the backend.  The order they are on the page is the order they'll be selected if you select them any way other than by ID.  When you save them to the database you assign an ID to them then.

Comment: @Archer ids are auto incremented in the database, the value in the hidden input fields are just the sort order numbers not the actual ids of the items.

Comment: Okay, but it's still overkill.  The elements are already in the correct order on the page, so any method of selecting them as a group will return them in that order.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different look at this - and focus on the desired result instead.....

Desired Result:

> I need this in order to save them to my ordering table in my database:

```
1 Item 3
2 Item 1
3 Item 2
```

As you didn't include how you are going to the db to save things, I will presume you will use jQuery and AJAX, which means you will use a serialize (or some method of viewing the ids as they appear on the page with their values).

So, my 'answer' (more of an extended comment...) is that you should look at the order they come into the .php (or whatever you are using for recording to the db) and use that as the 'order' method.

Of course, all this is based on a lot of conjecture though I trust it will give you an idea and direction to go with what you are trying to achieve.

It just seems to me from the work presented (in question/comments) that you may be losing sight of the forest because there are too many trees in the way..... (we all do it!)

Of course, if I mis-interpreted it, I'm happy to change the answer, though I'd like to see the 'Desired Result' be a bit more clear - and more code that sits around that - instead of trying to solve it on the front end (which I agree with @Archer to be 'overkill')

Hope this helps!